# SilverPOP API - Automated message report

Tags: export, message

I need to export all data from Silverpop automated message with silverpop API

apparently there are no many information on the net apart from the official guide "**XML API Developer’s Guide ENGAGE**"

I need to know how to:

- retrieve a list of Automated message
- extract / download data of selected report (for all days-not single one)

finally (again not documented in the official guide); how to programmatically export final report having set **MOVE_TO_FTP=true**
(the guide quotes *Use the MOVE_TO_FTP parameter to retrieve the output file programmatically*)

thank you very much in advance for any help in this

Comment: Looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RawRecipientDataExport XML API export to get the following:

•  One or more mailings
•  One or more Mailing/Report ID combinations (for Autoresponders)
•  A specific Database (optional: include related queries)
•  A specific Group of Automated Messages
•  An Event Date Range
•  A Mailing Date Range

For automated messages, you can use the following XML tags <CAMPAIGN_ACTIVE/>, <CAMPAIGN_COMPLETED/>, and <CAMPAIGN_CANCELLED/> to retrieve active Groups of Automated Messages, retrieve completed Groups of Automated Messages, and retrieve canceled Groups of Automated Messages, respectively.

To get data for all days and not just one, you can set a date range for send dates and event dates, by putting your desired date ranges within the <SEND_DATE_START> and <SEND_DATE_END> tags and <EVENT_DATE_START> and <EVENT_DATE_END> tags. The date formats are like this: 12/02/2011 23:59:00

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the message

I discovered that the result was empty due to START_DATE  / END_DATE missing (apparently necessary to get any result) !!!!